# Find the Min of Max values in a Map<String, List<Integer>> without relying on for loops

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a map of type `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>`.

I want to find the *maximum value* for each map entry, and in turn find the *minimum* of those *maximum values*.

I know this can be done using a couple of for loops. But was wondering if there's another way of doing it (maybe with streams?)

The final result I'm looking for is an integer.

*Example:*

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> values = new HashMap<>();

values.put("a", Arrays.asList(4, 8, 9, 10)); // max value is 10
values.put("b", Arrays.asList(20, 32, 1, 2)); // max value is 32
values.put("c", Arrays.asList(11, 50, 20, 6)); // max value is 50

// I need the min value out of the above maximums i.e. 10 (final answer)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the methods [Collections.min](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)) and [Collections.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection))

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

Integer min = Collections.min(myMap.values().stream().map(Collections::max).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to find the maximum value for each map entry and inturn find minimum of those maximum values.

Then [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) is your new friend. This object is meant to provide such information as *min* and *max* values, the number of consumed elements, *average* and their total.

As a container for the result, we can use a map `Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics>` that will hold *statistics* of every value mapped to this value's key. For that we need a help of collectors `flatMapping()` and `summarizingInt()`.

Then to get the *smallest maximum*, we should process the values of this *map*.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> sourceMap = 
    Map.of("a", List.of(4, 8, 9, 10),    // max value is 10
           "b", List.of(20, 32, 1, 2),   // max value is 32
           "c", List.of(11, 50, 20, 6)); // max value is 50
        
Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> statisticsByKey = sourceMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.flatMapping(entry -> entry.getValue().stream(), // flatens each list
            Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue))          // creates IntSummaryStatistics object based on the values of each list
    ));
    
statisticsByKey.forEach((k, v)
    -> System.out.println(k + " -> min: " + v.getMin() + " max: " + v.getMax()));
        
int smallestMaximum = statisticsByKey.values().stream()
    .mapToInt(IntSummaryStatistics::getMax)
    .min()        // produces OptionalInt as a result
    .orElse(-1);  // returns a default value of `-1` if result is not present
    
System.out.println("smallestMaximum: " + smallestMaximum);
```

*Output:*

```
a -> min: 4 max: 10
b -> min: 1 max: 32
c -> min: 6 max: 50

smallestMaximum: 10
```

*A link to the* [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rqi)

Comment: Your code finds the overall min and max (1 and 50 from OP's sample data), which is incorrect. OP wants the minimum of all the maximum values of each list.

Comment: @Bohemian Now it fetches *min* and *max* for every value.

Comment: Still incorrect. Your code doesn't produce the *single* result of `10` that OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Given a map

```
Hash<String, List<Integer>> values;
```

Find each list's max, then use `IntStream`'s `min()` over those:

```
Integer minMax = values.values().stream()
  .map(Collections::max)
  .mapToInt(n -> n).min().getAsInt();
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/xtmK6C) finding `10` from your sample data.

---

For the `IntStream` only version (probably more efficient), stream the values (ie the lists of integers), then find each list's max by converting each list to an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and getting its max, then find min of those:

```
Integer minMax = values.values().stream()
  .mapToInt(v -> v.stream().mapToInt(n -> n).max().getAsInt())
  .min().getAsInt();
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/ovZUcB).

This assumes all lists are not empty and the map itself is not empty.

---

There is also a way that makes use of `Collections.max(), but produces an` Optional` which is slightly more obtuse way IMHO

```
Integer minMax = values.values().stream()
    .map(Collections::max)
    .collect(Collectors.minBy(Integer::compareTo)).get();
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/qdnO4k).